# dotenv for api in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to place my connection string for an API in a .env file. My API is running off of localhost. My projects consist of microservices, so the frontend is running off of one port while the API is running off of a different port. I have installed dotenv. Below is the code, any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

This code is running on port 3000

Services

```
class TestService {
 private TEST_RESOURCE =  this.$resource(process.env.TEST_PORT);

 constructor(private $resource){}

 public getAll(){
  return this.TEST_RESOURCE.query();
 }
```

.env

```
TEST_PORT=http://localhost:8080/api/v1/weightclasses
```

app.ts (node)

```
require('dotenv').config({silent: true})
```

I was thinking that maybe there is something with localhost not being able to be used in .env as I have been playing with this for sometime. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If any other code or info is needed please let me know. I am not getting any errors in the console and the network tab is not showing anything either.

What works is the following code, but I would like to be able to use dotenv.

```
class TestService {
 private TEST_RESOURCE =  this.$resource("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/weightclasses");

 constructor(private $resource){}

 public getAll(){
  return this.TEST_RESOURCE.query();
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: localhost can be used with dotenv. what does your project structure look like? Where is the .env file in relation to your app.ts?

Comment: @Shane my .env is in my root directory, and my app.js is also in my root directory. the service is in root/ngApp/service/service.js

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the {silent: true} option. They haven't documented it yet, but the silent option suppresses the warnings that you get when you have problems with your .env file. If your app is not ready for production, I suggest to get the warnings and not suppress them with silent. By default silent is false unless changed.

source:
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/pull/66/commits/533346d4c4aef152efcae74f7442e19de64e3b7e